# skip other pipeline stages when executing a specific stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a declarative pipeline jenkinsfile, in which I have 4 stages.
I would like to make so that whenever a specific stage executes(this stage is conditional therefor it will not always execute), all stages after this one are skipped.
For example purposes let's say that this stage is the first stage.
Does anyone knows a way to do it in a declarative pipeline?

Thanks in advance,
Alon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a boolean variable e.g. `skip = false` in the pipeline. When you enter your conditional stage set the variable to `true`. Make other stages (2-4) dependent on `skip` variable.

```
stage("1 - Your conditional stage") {
  when {
    ...
  }
  steps {
    script {
      skip = true
    }
}

stage("2") {
  when {
    expression {
      return skip == false
    }
  }
}
...
stage("4") {
  when {
    expression {
      return skip == false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that work when the whole stages are inside a parallel matrix? I mean is the variable a different scope?